# TapGestureRecognizer onTap not triggering in webview_flutter

Tags: flutter, webview, gesture, webview-flutter

When I run the example below, the instance of `WebView` (from `webview_flutter` plugin) never calls `onTap`, no matter which URL I'm on.

Because `gestureRecognizers` override the widget's gestures, I'd assume that `onTap` should be called whenever there is a tap **anywhere** in my webview - I'm I assuming something wrong here?

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(WebViewBug());
}

class WebViewBug extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: WebView(
          initialUrl: 'https://google.com',
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          gestureRecognizers: {
            Factory<TapGestureRecognizer>(() => TapGestureRecognizer()
              ..onTap = () {
                print('didTap');
              }),
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Flutter version used is `2.5.2`.